# Execute npm install command after one-click publish in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, npm-install, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have enabled one-click publish with IIS Web Deploy for my MVC5 application. I would like to be able to execute the 'npm install' command in the publish directory ideally after the files have been published.

I understand that via command-line, I can use the 'postsync' argument to execute a command, but is it possible to modify my .pubxml file to include a command that will execute the 'npm install' command? (therefore I can publish directly from Visual Studio without having to use command-line).